# How do I add a second tabular model to the same SSAS database

Tags: model, ssas, tabular

I'm new to SSAS. I'm trying to build two tabular data models in Visual Studio 2017 which I'd like to deploy to the same SSAS database.

I've built both models as separate projects within the same solution. When I deploy the solution though the second one over writes the first model. (I think I've given them different names where ever I can see).

I don't seem to be able to find a way to have a second model within the same project.

Hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Many thanks

Ben

Comment: Why do you want it in the same database? That’s not supported. What’s the disadvantage of a second database?

Answer (score 1):

SSAS tabular supports one model per database. SSAS multidimensional supports multiple cubes per database.

Analytics is about management of business processes and specific subject areas.

For me multiples and specialized models make sense.

Also intelligence is specific for each subject area

One size does not fit all

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you are having trouble deploying a new database (model) to your current SSAS server? If so try the following:

1. In VS, in the 'Solution Explorer' right click on your Project
   folder, this should be above your .bim file and below your solution
   folder, and select the 'Properties' option. A property page will
   open up. Ensure that the 'Databse' and 'Model Name' are unique i.e.
   not the same as your previous model and database.
2. In the 'Solution Explorer' right click on the .bim file and select
   the 'Properties' option. Ensure that the 'Workspace Database' name
   is not the same as the original project 'Workspace Database' name.

Once these options have been configured to be distinct from your original model/database, you should see your new model upon deployment to the server.